# Google Maps Javascript - Disable 3d view when zoomed in

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-apps-script, google-api, google-apps

Is there a way to disable google maps from going to 3d mode when zooming in?

I would like to keep it like this, just zoomed in:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0ymO.jpg)

But when I zoom in currently, it 3d renders the buildsings:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UOYE.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the [45-degree imagery](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#45DegreeImagery) in Satellite view. You can set [`tilt: 0`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/map#MapOptions.tilt) in the `MapOptions` when initializing the map to avoid the map using that imagery when zoomed in very close. Here's a [simple sample JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yolicohiwe/edit?html,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.422009,-122.084302),
          tilt: 0,
          mapTypeId: "satellite",
          zoom: 19
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```